# What is a good IDE for coding NASM?

Tags: eclipse, ide, nasm

I've been doing research online to find a good IDE for programming in NASM. The only one I found consistently mention is [RadASM](http://radasm.cherrytree.at/download/?did=40) however, in contains no documentation on how to set it up and on top of that it is riddled with viruses/trojans (according to Norton).

Does anyone know of a reliable, preferably free, IDE that works well with NASM?

I'm looking for something to do the same for NASM as NetBeans or Eclipse do for Java.

Comment: Visual Studio can be set up to do this, although the syntax highlighting will be wonky (you can write a plugin for it, I've done this for using the MASM assembler, but you can't use a plugin on the express/free edition of VS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some links to IDE's [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285068-assembler-getting-started/)

Both RadASM v2 and v3 are from the authors sourcforge repository site and are virus free

**Update**
Because the links are broken on the above page, I'm adding the git info [here](https://github.com/mrfearless/RadASM2).

Comment: Do you know where I can find a manual on how to use it? I'm trying to compile a really simple program but it's telling me it can't find the .exe file??  Also it's not saving any files...

Comment: Click the help menu and read the help file????  You need to set the paths to tell RadASM where to find nasm.  You could edit the ini files or Option > Set Paths and point to your NASM folder.  Personally, I use Geany for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: The help files are rather useless to someone who isn't already a pro. Thanks for the tip regarding the path.  Do you happen to know more specifically why it gives me error "can't find the .exe file"?

Comment: Chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26315/radasm

Comment: The links to RadASM are not working (404). Added link to the git source.